# Laravel error exception route not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I start a new laravel project make composed by two pages, I created the pages under the `app/view` directory and this is my `route.php` file:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('welcome', function()
{
    return View::make('welcome');
});

Route::any('signup', function()
{
    return View::make('signup');
});
```

I can access to the pages signup by taping the link directly in the browser and also when I run artisan routes it shows me the routes that I created.
in the `welcome.blade.php` when I add the line

```
{{link_to_route('signup')}}
```

and reload the page I have this error

```
ErrorException
Route [signup] not defined. (View: C:\wamp\www\atot\app\views\welcome.blade.php)
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Route::any('signup', [
    'as' => 'signup',
    function() {
        return View::make('signup');
    }
]);
```

Your problem was that you didn't use a named route.

If you want, you can read more about it here: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 1):

Link_to_route is a method that generates a url to a given *[named route](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes)*, so to make it work you can name each of your routes and then it will work

```
  link_to_route('route.name', $title, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array());
```

In routes.php update the following

```
Route::get('/', array('as'=>'home', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}));

Route::get('welcome', array('as'=>'welcome', function()
{
    return View::make('welcome');
}));

Route::any('signup', array('as'=>'signup', function()
{
    return View::make('signup');
}));
```

Then you can generate the following routes:

```
{{link_to_route('home')}}
{{link_to_route('welcome')}}
{{link_to_route('signup')}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use either:

```
{{ link_to('signup') }}
```

Or declare the route using a name

```
Route::any('signup', array('as' => 'signup', function()
{
    // ...
}));
```

The `link_to_route` [helper function](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers) only works with a named route which accepts a route name in the first argument.